# Is there a way to use SVG filter primitives to differentially modify polyline/path segments?

Tags: javascript, svg, svg-filters

I've been scouring the [SVG documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/filters.html#FilterPrimitivesOverview) for a way to do this, without any success, and I'm wondering if I've missed something simple (or even not so simple).

I have a pattern to apply to my SVG, and it's easy enough to produce a pattern that I could use as input to an [`feImage`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/filters.html#feImageElement) `filter` element, but my problem is that the orientation of that pattern to the vector representing the direction of the path segment needs to remain constant for each segment.

I *could* mimic this effect by, for example, breaking up the paths so that only segments with similar orientation are used with a given rotation of the `feImage`, and with something like 20 different orientations (or maybe 36-- I haven't done the experiment) I could probably get an acceptable effect, but a conservative estimate of the effect this would have on my (code-generated) SVG is that it would probably double the size of my files, and sometimes would be worse.

Simultaneous to this effect, I want to be able to treat the segments as though they are rising and falling along the segment, and to apply lighting as if this is the case. I can easily parametrize this rise and fall, so that I can apply the changes in the alpha channel to the segment, but I can't see how I would apply such a transformation segment-by-segment.

Is there a way to modify path or polyline segments in the ways I've described?

Comment: I suspect canvas would be a better fit for you rather than trying to knock in your requirements screw with an SVG hammer.

Comment: I suspect you're right, but other needs have precluded considering that option up to this point!

Comment: Time for a reevaluation then.

Comment: a quick image showing what you're trying to do would be super helpful

Comment: You can see two examples ![here](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-92vujRis8kc/VSvbb0V80bI/AAAAAAAAADA/uG8_3CVcbBM/w949-h559-no/3d-effect-demo.PNG) and ![here](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-THTBftTR0Zk/VSvbb60ABBI/AAAAAAAAADA/nFq5ahctKeE/w906-h692-no/effect-2.PNG).

Comment: The first example is very dense from the perspective of the number of SVG elements in the view. The second is relatively sparse. If you examine either image carefully, you'll note shading that indicates the endpoints of individual polyline segments. This is the effect I wish to duplicate.

Comment: So +1 to what Robert said - this is what Canvas was made for :)